# Automatically click a "Sign" button anywhere on screen

Tags: button, find, screen, ui-automation, signing

Every week I have tons of documents to sign. I have written a java program that can automatically move mouse to designated positions and click. This tremendously helped with part of my work.

However, some other documents are managed by a Siemens software that opens up a PDF file and displays on it a "Sign" button, and each document has the "Sign" button in different locations within that Siemens software.

How can I write a program to find this "Sign" button anywhere on the screen, so that I can modify my existing program to move mouse there to sign it? This can save me 20 minutes at least every 3 to 4 days, and that adds up.

Answer (score 0):

A high level process would be: Take a screenshot of your screen, run it through some OCR software, and get a position to pass on